# MAC OS Mojave slow application launch

Tags: macos-mojave

I ran into a rare problem. suddenly about a week ago my mac book pro started to act weirdly. when i try to launch my third party apps like XCode,Firefox and even my own apps, the app icon starts bouncing on the dock for like 20-30 times and usually it takes 10-15 seconds for my apps to open.Except Firefox my other apps works fine as soon as they got launched. my RAM and CPU usage is normal and i have about 50GB free space on my current partition.my hard drive is SSD.

ps: apple native apps like preferences and apple store or even iTunes launches very fast.

Macbookpro 2017 
RAM:16
CPU:i7 
HDD: 512GB SSD

i have tried resetting SMC and PRAM.I ran first aid on my partition there was no problem.

any other solutions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to launch some misbehaving application from console, see if they print error messages and what.

Comment: @uprego nope, nothing, it just takes 5-8 seconds to get executed!

Comment: That's not a corporate laptop, is it?

Comment: i don't get what do you mean by corporate but i have written my laptop's config